# TypeError: Cannot set property of null while using local storage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage, angular-local-storage

My code has been working well until I introduced local storage. What I do is: when device is ready check if the values exist, if so get them. In the body of a function I assign a value to that variable scope and that's where I get this error.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if (localStorageService.get("modelTrue") == null) {
  $scope.userModal.show();
  localStorageService.set("modelTrue", "true")
}
else {
  //Parameter to restore:
  if(localStorageService.get("first") != null){
    $scope.data.firstDisplay = JSON.parse(localStorageService.get("first"));
  }
}; 
$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
                 $scope.data.firstDisplay = {'src' : 'img/1.png'}; //this is where I get the error
                 localStorageService.set("first", JSON.stringify($scope.data.firstDisplay));   
              }
```

When I call the last function I get the error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstDisplay' of null".

I don't understand this behaviour. I am simply setting a variable to a value.
What might this mean?

The null comes from console.log($scope.data);
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare   `$scope.data ={}`; otherwise it is always null,

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $scope.data ={};
            if (localStorageService.get("modelTrue") == null) {
                $scope.userModal.show();
                localStorageService.set("modelTrue", "true")
            } else {
                //Parameter to restore:
                if (localStorageService.get("first") != null) {
                    $scope.data.firstDisplay = JSON.parse(localStorageService.get("first"));
                }
            };
            $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
                $scope.data.firstDisplay = {
                    'src': 'img/1.png'
                }; //this is where I get the error
                localStorageService.set("first", JSON.stringify($scope.data.firstDisplay));
            }
```

Comment: declare what? $scope.data is already declared inside my controller. This.ready is inside my controller as well.

Comment: are you sure, can you put a console.log before setting $scope.data.firstDisplay and post here

Comment: see it is null there , that is the issue

Comment: initially it is empty. But I dont understand, it used to work perfectly before, just when i added a local storage it got this error. Shouldn't the  $scope.data i defined in the beginning of the controller suffice?

Comment: It's sufficient, probably you are setting empty in some part of the code